# Sonomotors, Sion: Can this electric car really charge up to 30km only from its solar cells?

Tags: electrical-engineering, solar-energy, car

Maybe you have heard about Sonomotors and its futuristic electric car, the Sion.
If not, here is the link to its website: https://sonomotors.com/

[image]

Anyway, the manufacturer claims that this car can recharge up to 30km on one day using its own solar-cells.

I have come to Physics Stackexchange, because I want to know: **Can this be true ?**

(I am looking for well-researched, fact based, answers without any bias for or against this car.)

EDIT: got some good answers... but let's really crack it down... Can we chose Germany for instance, look at the solar radiation per month and compute an expected range per month?

Answer (score 1):

It could well be true, but that doesn't mean it is useful.

Pick a day in the middle of summer, with a clear sky. Go to a flat test track. Spend 6 hours (three hours each side of midday) driving round it at walking pace, say 5km/h.

Oops, I forgot to tell you to inflate the tires to 50% higher pressure than normal, to reduce rolling resistance. They won't blow if you are only doing 5km/h on a perfectly maintained surface.

Congratulations, you have now traveled 30km in a day using only solar cells. But so what?